# Custom desktop launcher no control or link from taskbar icon

Tags: unity, scripts, launcher, gnome-shell, .desktop

I use several self made scripts in my ubuntu 20.04 to make my life easier. I put some of them into desktop launchers.

But the vanilla-launchers (*.desktop files) have no control from the taskbar icon:

1. **Highlight Feature:** When I click on one of them, it appears in the dash (if not already) and then a single dot appears on it implying one instance of it is already running.
2. **Close Option:** I am also unable to close it (SIGKILL) via a close option menu.

[image]

I have been wondering for long on how to do it on .desktop file side or application script side.
Any side solution works for me, I am curious how to configure that.